# SQL: find based on previous id

Tags: mysql

I have a table like follows:

```
mysql> select * from tries;
+----+--------+-----------+
| id | person | succeeded |
+----+--------+-----------+
|  1 |      1 |         1 |
|  2 |      1 |         1 |
|  3 |      2 |         0 |
|  4 |      4 |         1 |
|  5 |      2 |         1 |
|  6 |      2 |         0 |
|  7 |      3 |         0 |
|  8 |      3 |         0 |
|  9 |      3 |         0 |
| 10 |      1 |         0 |
| 11 |      4 |         1 |
| 12 |      4 |         1 |
+----+--------+-----------+
```

I want the people who had (at least) one `try` that succeeded, following a `try` that failed (given by `1` and `0`, respectively). When I say "follow", I mean the previous attempt by the same person, given by a lower `id`.

So in this case:

- Person 2 succeeded on `id = 5`, and failed on `id = 3`, that person's previous try, thus **meets** the criteria.
- Person 1 has no successes that immediately follow failures, thus fails the criteria
- Person 3 has no successes, thus fails the criteria
- Person 4 has no failures, thus fails the criteria

How would I write such a query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.person, MIN(t1.id) as SuccessID
    FROM tries t1
    WHERE t1.succeeded = 1
        AND t1.person IN (SELECT t2.person
                              FROM tries t2
                              WHERE t2.succeeded = 0
                                  AND t2.id < t1.id)
    GROUP BY t1.person
```

Comment: This could have a second succeed try between the first one and the first failed try.

Comment: @Ronaldo: I'm not sure I'm following you. Can you give a concrete example?

Comment: @Ronaldo: correct, although since Joe is grouping by t1.person, it doesn't matter, since if there is a second succeeded try between the first one and first failed try, then the person meets the criteria.

Comment: I got what you saying. I was reading in such a way that a person could have just that sequence to meet the criteria. @Joe answer looks like is giving the correct value.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select ...
From tries As T
    Join tries As T2
        On T2.id = T.id + 1
            And T2.succeeded = 0
Where T.succeeded = 1
```

If we cannot assume Ids are perfectly contiguous:

```
Select ...
From tries As T
    Join    (
            Select T1.id, Min(T2.Id) As NextId
            From tries As T1
                Join tries As T2
                    On T2.id > T.id
            Group By T1.id
            ) As TriesAndNext
        On TriesAndNext.Id = T.Id
    Join tries As TNext
        On TNext.Id = TriesAndNext.NextId
            And TNext.succeeded = 0
Where T.succeeded = 1
```

Comment: The IDs are not always sequential as I understand the question.

Comment: @Ronaldo Junior - Have amended my answer to allow for that scenario.